# How do I get characters from a .txt and use it to replace other character in files?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter

I need to change characters in a list of files inside a folder I have as input. For the matching characters, I use another file which provides me something like this :

## /a# = á

## /A# = Á

## :A# = Ä

I use substring to store each of these characters inside 2 arrays, 1 array for the character to replace and another one with the replacing character. Then I do this :

```
 public static void renameFile(File fileOriginal, String[] arrayToConvert, String[] arrayConverted) throws IOException {
        File destination = new File(fileOriginal + "");         

      try {             File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
            Reader fr = new FileReader(fileOriginal);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while (br.ready()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.length ; i++){        
        fw.write(br.readLine().replace(arrayToConvert[i], arrayConverted[i]));                      

            }           }
```

But it doesn't work, before I was using :

```
    while (br.ready()) {
            fw.write(br.readLine().replace("#/A#" , "Á").  
                    replace("#/a#" , "á").  
                    replace("#:A#" , "Ä").  
                    replace("#:a#" , "ä")
```

And it worked but now That I am getting my characters from a file, how should I do to do it the most efficient way ? I'm using java 1.6.

Thanks.

Comment: As long as there are input lines available, repeat these steps: 1) Read next line; 2) apply the replacements one by on using a loop; 3) write out the result.

Answer (score 0):

If i unterstand correctly what you want to archieve. The Issue is in this Section:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.length ; i++){        
    fw.write(br.readLine().replace(arrayToConvert[i], arrayConverted[i]));                      
}
```

When you execute the code you read only line 0 to arrayToConvert.length and thats not what you want.

So a better way is to read every line and convert it.

this could be done in a way like this:

```
String s = null;
while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
   for(int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.length ; i++){        
     s = s.replace(arrayToConvert[i], arrayConverted[i]);                      
   }
   fw.write(s);       
}
```

Or to explain in a not code way:

1. Read the Line as long as there are lines
2. run your replac logic
3. write the converted line to the new file

Comment: I got NullPointerException with your code and I dont understand why.